# Print Googlemap with markers and markerClusters

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, printing

I want to print put a google map, created with the Googlemaps API v3.0 including simple markers and markerClusters.

Here is the code which produces the map:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

    var mcStyles = [{
      textColor: 'white',
      url: 'images/clusterIcon.png',
      height: 50,
      width: 50
    }];
    var mcOptions = {
        gridSize: 1,
        zoomOnClick: false,
        styles: mcStyles
    };
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);

    //markerCluster should be always above the geocoder-->
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    console.log(cities.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
      var city = cities[i];
      geocodeCity(city, markerCluster);
    }
```

Now I want to print out the entire map, including markers and markerclusters using the Google Chrome browser. 
I am not able to do this. With one solution I see the markers only,

```
var printMaps = function () {
      console.log('printMaps');

      var content = window.document.getElementById('map') // get you map details
      console.log(content);
      var newWindow = window.open(); // open a new window
      newWindow.document.write(content.innerHTML); // write the map into the new window
      newWindow.print(); // print the new window
    }
    $('#button-print').on('click', printMaps);
```

with another one only the map with the clusters but without the simple markers.

```
var printMaps = function () {
      var body               = $('body'),
          mapContainer       = $('#map'),
          mapContainerParent = mapContainer.parent(),

          printContainer     = $('<div>');

      body.prepend(printContainer);
      printContainer
          .addClass('print-container')
          .css('position', 'relative')
          .height(mapContainer.height())
          .append(mapContainer);

      var content = body.children()
          .not('script')
          .not(printContainer)
          .detach();

      console.log(content);

      window.print();

      body.prepend(content);
      mapContainerParent.prepend(mapContainer);
      printContainer.remove();
    };

    $('#button-print').on('click', printMaps);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

See: [MarkerClusterer Printing Issue](https://github.com/seancallinan/google-maps-utility-library-v3/issues/79)

MarkerClusterer does not print, however the [MarkerClustererPlus](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus) library overcomes this limitation.